# Power method on the matrix (basic question)

Tags: matrices

I have a question: With the starting vector $\mathbf{x}(0) = (1, 0)$, I need to compute two iterations of the power
method on the matrix $$A = \left(\begin{matrix}2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2\end{matrix}\right).$$

Comment: I don't think I agree that you have asked a question. You should tell us more about what is the trouble in completing your task.

Comment: Again, what is preventing you from doing this yourself?  It seems to me that this is just a matter of arithmetic.  You wouldn't ask us for help in performing $2+2$, what is the difference here?